# How uWSGI master communicates with processes/workers?

Tags: python, uwsgi

When we do the following command

`uwsgi --master --worker 4 --http-socket 0.0.0.0:8001 --wsgi-file ./examples/flaskpost.py`

`spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 38968)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 38969, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 38970, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 3 (pid: 38971, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 4 (pid: 38972, cores: 1)`

How uWSGI master communication with workers? (signal?)
What is the underlying mechanism?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Communication and event management are all managed by the same subsystem – the uWSGI signal framework.
https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Signals.html